# Proving that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n \sin (\frac{1}{3^nx})$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence

> Show that the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^n \sin (\frac{1}{3^nx})$$ does
>   not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$

Solution:
[image]

My **question** is what is the technique being used in the solution to show that the series does not converge uniformly?  Can anyone explain it with reference to the relevant definition/theorem?

---

What I don't understand is that how showing that $$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty} 2^n \sin (\frac{1}{3^nx})$$ cannot be made arbitrarily small proves the result.  This answer seems more like its showing that the sequence of partial sums is unbounded.  I need clarification.

Comment: the point is, the function converges at different speed, and as x approaches 0, this speed becomes very slow so that there is no uniform speed for the convergence

Comment: What book are you reading?

Comment: @Jack Spivak's Caculus (3rd Ed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is the technique being used in the solution to show that the series does not converge uniformly

Go back to the **[definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition)**. I will explain it abstractly here.

Consider a sequence of functions $f_n:E\to{\bf R}$, where $E$ is some subset of ${\bf R}$. There are two basic modes of convergence of the sequence $\{f_n\}$.

- If for each $x\in E$, $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$, we say that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise. In terms of the $\epsilon$-$N$ language, 
  $$
  \forall x\in E\ \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N\in{\bf N}\ 
  \forall n\geq N\ \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\tag{1}
  $$
- We say $f_n$ converges to $f$ *uniformly*, if the following is true:
  $$
   \forall \epsilon>0\ \exists N\in{\bf N}\ 
  \forall n\geq N\ \forall x\in E\ \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\tag{2}
  $$

Note that (2) is a *stronger* condition than (1).

Remember that a series is nothing but the limit of a partial sum. Suppose $g_n:(0,\infty)\to{\bf R}$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x)$ converges uniformly **means**, the sequence of functions $f_k$, defined with
$$
f_k(x):=\sum_{n=0}^k g_n(x),
$$
converges uniformly to some function $g:(0,\infty)\to{\bf R}$.

---

Now, note that $f_k$ does not converge uniformly on $(0,\infty)$ means (2) is not true, namely the following holds:
$$
 \exists \epsilon>0\ \forall N\in{\bf N}\ 
\exists n\geq N\ \exists x\in E\ \ |f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq \epsilon\tag{3}
$$

It is an instructive exercise to check how your "solution" matches (3).

Answer (score 1):

**By definition:** a  series $\sum_{ n=0}^{\infty} a_n(x)$  converges uniformly iff:
$$ \lim_{N\to \infty}\sup_{x\in\Bbb R} \left|\sum_{ n=N}^{\infty} a_n(x)\right| =0$$

see here: [Explain $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sup_{x\in\Bbb R} \left|\sum_{ n=N}^{\infty} a_n(x)\right| =0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533476/explain-lim-n-to-infty-sup-x-in-bbb-r-left-sum-n-n-infty-a-nx-r?noredirect=1#comment5231473_2533476)

> **They essentially used the following well known inequality**
>
> For all $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$
> We have,
> $$\frac{2}{\pi}x\le \sin x\le x$$

As follows: for very large $N\in\Bbb N,$ Taking $ \color{blue}{x =\frac{2}{3^N\pi}}$ and using the geometric sum we obtain:

$$\infty =\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)} \left|\sum_{ n=N}^{\infty} 2^n \sin (\frac{1}{3^nx}) \right| \overset{\color{blue}{x =\frac{2}{3^N\pi}} }{\ge}  \sum_{ n=N}^{\infty} 2^n \sin (\frac{3^N\pi}{3^n2})\\\ge  \sum_{ n=N}^{\infty} 3^N \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n=  3.2^N.$$

That is $$\infty = \lim_{N\to \infty}\sup_{x\in(0,\infty)} \left|\sum_{ n=N}^{\infty} 2^n \sin (\frac{1}{3^nx}) \right| \ge   \lim_{N\to \infty}2^N =\infty.$$
**Which will prove the non-uniformly convergence for your series.**

Comment: My book doesn't seem to present that definition.  It seems to be similar to the vanishing condition for a series that converges.  Is that right?  Also what does the $\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}$ represent?

Comment: what is the definition in your book . it must be equivalent to this one. ch3ck carefully

Comment: @helios321 you seem to be spektical with this definition

Comment: A little bit, I have another post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533476/explain-lim-n-to-infty-sup-x-in-bbb-r-left-sum-n-n-infty-a-nx-r?noredirect=1#comment5231473_2533476

Comment: @heliose321 the answer there is perfectly correct.  I upvoted it . you should do the same. unless you have another definition you would like to share with you us

Comment: Why a down vote?